# Access Import CSV file

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to import a CSV file into Access. However the way the CSV file is formatted, it creates three lines for the same transaction. Is it possible to tell Access that every three lines belong to the same transaction when creating or appending the table? VBA is fine, if that's the only way possible.

Currently during the import for one transaction, Access creates 8 fields for the first line, 29 fields for the second line, and 8 more for the third line. I would either prefer having the 48 fields for the one transaction or telling access I only need certain fields.  For example, I need only field 2 of the first line, field 11 of the second line and field3 of the third line for each transaction.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Probably should add the Access or VBA tag since your question is application specific.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any way of doing that within access. However CSV is a very specific format and the way yours is laid out is incorrect according to CSV standards. It should be a single record to a line.

Use an advanced text editor such as Sublime or Notepad++ to edit the CSV file such that each newline character actually represents the end of a record.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying to create a new database for our fuel system. The fuel system creates a report in only doc, excel and csv. With the current database, they get the doc report and enter all the fields manually. It becomes a pain since there are at times hundreds of transactions. The csv is created by the fuel system. The database has to be updated weekly. Both the doc and excel files are generated like in a gas receipt format.

Comment: I was looking at the csv file and I see that the first line is the title of the company along with the date query. The second line is the tittles of the things queried (like gas qty, user, date) and the third line are the actual things queried this would be the information i need for the database.

Comment: Sounds like whatever software that controls the output from the fuel system is lying to you about creating a valid CSV. Speak to whoever works with that to modify the output so it is valid. Alternavively write a bit of code that will modify the CSV prior to import. Although I could do this, it opens up a far bigger topic of modules and VBA coding which would require a lot more learning on your part to implement